# Does chaining LINQ statements result in multiple iterations?

Tags: performance, linq

Does chaining LINQ statements result in multiple iterations?

For example, let's say I want to filter my data with a where clause, and then on the matches do a sum:

```
int total = data.Where(item => item.Alpha == 1 && item.Beta == 2)
    .Sum(item => item.Qty);
```

Does this result in a single interation of the data, such that it would be equivalent to this?

```
int total = 0;
foreach (var item in data)
    if (item.Alpha == 1 && item.Beta == 2)
        total += 1;
```

Or, does it iterate over `data` once, and the results of the `where` a second time to do the sum?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statements in LINQ are streamed, so `Where` does not actually run until `Sum` enumerates through its values.  This means the items from `data` will effectively be enumerated a single time.

Basically, the `Where` method creates a new `IEnumerable<T>`, but doesn't actually enumerate through `data`.  `Sum` does a `foreach` over the `IEnumerable<T>` from `Where`, which in turn pulls items through the `Where` sequence one at a time.

Comment: I understand that it is deferred until evaluated, but does it iterate twice? Once for the where, and once for the sum?

Comment: @Matt It doesn't really "iterate" until it gets to `Sum`.  I tried to edit to be more clear.

Comment: Great!  Other than doing a .ToList() or .ToArray(), are there any LINQ queries that would result in multiple enumerations?

Comment: @Matt `ToList()`/`ToArray()` does not perform multiple enumerations (unless you're starting new query from the collection they return).

Comment: @Matt `ToList()`/`ToArray()` in the middle of a query will evalulate it at that point, since it has to build the list.   If you do statements afterwards, it'll do a new enumeration.  If you do it at the end, it still will only enumerate once.

Comment: @Matt Yes. `OrderBy` and `Reverse`. Basically, anything that would require a full enumeration in order to determine the **first** value.

Comment: @nmclean `Reverse` is sad - in theory, any IList could be reversed without that, but there isn't an optimization for that in the framework :(

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that LINQ query will cause only one iteration over source collection.

How it works? `Sum` *asks* for one element at the time and so does `Where` (on source collection). So when `Sum` need next element, it calls `MoveNext` on `Enumerator<T>` taken from `Where`, which is implemented as following:

```
foreach(var item in source)
    if(predicate(item))
        yield return item;
```

To understand it more you should read about iterators: [Iterators (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx)